# How to pass widget's own data to a function

Tags: flutter, dart

Learning Flutter and came up with this problem. I have no clue how to refer to widget's own data. My solution might not be the best solution.

```dart
class ClassA extends StatelessWidget {

    void myFunction(MyDataClass data) {...}

    @override
    Widget build(Buildcontext context) {
    return ClassB(
            data: MyDataClass(...),
            onTap: myFunction(???),
        );
    }
}
```

I need to get ClassB's data (MyDataClass) to the function myFunction. Is there some way to achieve this?

Comment: Your approach is correct. Where are you stuck at? Put some more code of ClassB

Comment: I need to pass ClassB's data tag to myFunction when tapped. What's the syntax for this? myFunction(this.data)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there's a smarter way to do this but at least this works:

```
class ClassA extends StatelessWidget {

    void myFunction(MyDataClass data) {...}

    MyDataClass someData = MyDataClass(...);

    @override
    Widget build(Buildcontext context) {
    return ClassB(
            data: someData,
            onTap: () => myFunction(someData),
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for soothing like this.. try if this works

```
class ClassB extends StatelessWidget {
   Function(MyDataClass) onTap;

   ClassB(this.onTap);


   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                     MyDataClass yourData = MyDataClass(...);
                     onTap(yourData);
              },
        )
   }
}
```

```
class ClassA extends StatelessWidget {

    void myFunction(MyDataClass data) {...}

    @override
    Widget build(Buildcontext context) {
    return ClassB(
            data: MyDataClass(...),
            onTap: myFunction,
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice try but doesn't work. Gives error on line `onTap(MyDataClass);`.

Comment: onTap(MyDataClass); here MyDataClass should be a object (data that you want to pass ) not the class. I just put it for show...

Comment: image MyDataClass is String so onTap will be onTap("data")

Comment: I guess storing `MyDataClass` in a variable should do the trick

Comment: Yes that's what I meant, create an object from the class you want to send data